# Ссылка на статью про избранные вопросы

Tags: дефект, локализация, избранное

Если участник ещё ничего не добавлял в избранное, то в его [профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/104/hask?tab=favorites) содержится текст со ссылкой:

> [image: нет избранных]

Ссылка ведёт на вопрос на Meta.SE: [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Имеет смысл либо перевести эту статью (либо использовать имеющуюся русскоязычную, если таковая действительно есть) и дать ссылку уже на неё.

Comment: Хорошо бы все такие заглушки, ведущие на английскую мету и блог перевести.

Comment: @Nofate а есть где-то общий список таких "заглушек"?

Comment: Сомневаюсь. Нужно сидеть и все прокликивать. Можно выделить под это отдельный вопрос на мете и попытаться собрать в него что-то вроде оглавления непереведнных ссылок из справки.

Comment: @Nofate ну, если ещё что найдется - можно и подумать об этом. В принципе бОльшая часть уже локализована.