# Ссылка на статью при блокировке участника

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, блокировка

[Ещё](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4170/176217) одна ссылка на не руссифицированную статью видна при просмотре профиля заблокированного участника:

> [image: временно заблокирована]

Ссылка ведёт на страницу: [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

Хорошо бы сделать перевод и давать ссылку на него.

Comment: Перевод статьи сделан: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6703/208074

Comment: Поменяли ссылку)