# Блокировка и её последствия

Tags: обсуждение, faq, модерация, профиль-участника, перевод-блога

Что такое блокировка? За что она даётся и на какой срок? Будут ли какие-нибудь последствия после окончания блокировки?

Answer (score 15):

*Данный ответ является переводом статьи Джеффа Этвуда «[A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)».*

---

Вам знакомо такое понятие, как штрафная скамья?

*Скамейка для оштрафованных игроков (она же скамейка штрафников, штрафная скамья) — специально выделенное место в хоккее, регби-футболе и некоторых других видах спорта, в котором игроки находятся за поступки, недостаточно серьёзные для дисквалификации.*

Изначально этого не планировалось, но мы **вводим на Stack Overflow скамейку для оштрафованных игроков**.

Наша задача — пресекать *поступки*, а не отдельно взятых участников. Но порой уговоры не действуют на нарушителей, и на них приходится накладывать временную блокировку.

Когда участник упорно проявляет:

- **нежелание обучаться и улучшать свои навыки**, а именно:

  1. Не прилагает усилий для грамотного формулирования своих вопросов;
  2. Не желает расширять свои знания по теме своих вопросов и нормам поведения сообщества;
  3. Упорно множит один и тот же вопрос, возможно, с небольшими вариациями;
  4. Ничего не даёт сообществу взамен, а только берёт;
- **неконструктивное поведение**, а именно вызывает:

  1. Массовую недоброжелательную реакцию на свой вклад, а также склоки;
  2. Возмущение насчёт своего поведения, активно обсуждаемое в чате сообщества;
  3. Шквал *флагов, требующих внимание модератора*, буквально преследующий его на каждом шагу,

... это *требует* вмешательства. В противном случае подобное поведение будет бессмысленно занимать модераторское время или, что ещё хуже, **отпугнёт посетителей от сообщества, угнетая его рост и принося всем вред**.

Поэтому отныне *у любого проявления неподобающего поведения будут последствия*.

[image: Штрафная скамья]

Если, по нашему мнению, вы не переступили черту и ещё можете исправиться, мы сначала *попробуем* связаться с вами через электронную почту до того, как ситуация усугубится. Но не факт, что всё будет именно так. Модераторы достаточно загружены, а потому вероятность подобного контакта будет зависеть исключительно от вашего предшествующего вклада в сообщество, то есть вашей ценности как участника.

Если вы проигнорируете модераторское предупреждение, ваша учётная запись будет **временно заблокирована** на срок от дня до года, в зависимости от степени серьёзности вашего поведения. Это означает, что:

- ваша репутация будет понижена до единицы,
- на вашей странице участника будет размещена плашка, сигнализирующая о факте и сроке блокировки,
- вы не сможете голосовать, спрашивать, отвечать и комментировать.

По окончании периода блокировки **все вышеперечисленные ограничения будут отменены**. Мы не мстительные. Всё это необходимо исключительно для пресечения конкретной проблемы. Проблема исчерпана? Добро пожаловать обратно.

И ещё. Это должно быть очевидным, но если вы упорно будете продолжать неподобающе себя вести, ваша учётная запись с большой вероятностью будет удалена.