# Участник удалил текст вопроса и добавил стихотворение

Tags: обсуждение, правки, хулиганство

Один участник (@yeh) задал нормальный вопрос, но потом его "правил": удалил текст вопроса и добавил туда... Стихотворение! Вот эта "правка":
[image: стихотворение]

Потом другой участник вернул всё, как было, но есть вероятность, что "правки" продолжаться.

Вопрос: как бороться с такого рода хулиганством? [Вот временная шкала вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1495191/timeline), а вот
[сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1495191/hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы увидели, что с постом произошло нечто страшное, нечто подобное, вот, что следует предпринять:

1. Оставьте тревогу последнего типа ("требуется вмешательство модератора"), написав что автор поста решил изуродовать свой пост. Модератор одобрит тревогу и заблокирует пост от любых дальнейших правок на N дней (есть такая причина блокировки - споры по контенту поста), а также, может быть, [вынесет временный бан](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6703/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F) владельцу поста на неделю
2. Если у вас есть [привилегии для мгновенного редактирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (от 2,000 репутации), вы можете сделать откат до предыдущей версии. Не стоит вступать в бои с владельцем поста, если он решит снова исковеркать пост: вы уже оставили тревогу на первом шагу, просто подождите
3. Если у вас нет привилегий для мгновенного редактирования, остановитесь на первом шаге: бессмысленно предлагать правку для возврата поста к исходному состоянию, это лишняя трата времени: саму правку может отклонить владелец поста

Comment: Тут следует добавить, что если запрос заминусован и не имеет ответов, можно автору тонко намекнуть на возможность его удалить. Если вопрос и до вандализма был плох, нет смысла заморачиваться с откатом на предыдущую версию, и тем более тревогой модератору.

Answer (score 2):

Бороться - очень просто:

- Если нету репатации на откат правки - ставить тревогу для модератора.
- Если есть репутация - делать откат правки.
- Если ТС упорствует и делает откат отката - ставить тревогу для модератора.

Comment: при частых откатах тревога модераторам приходит автоматически