# В каких случаях перед блокировкой даётся модераторское предупреждение?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, блокировка

Есть такой вопрос [Блокировка и её последствия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6703/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F) и там сказано:

> Если, по нашему мнению, вы не переступили черту и ещё можете исправиться, мы сначала попробуем связаться с вами через электронную почту до того, как ситуация усугубится. Но не факт, что всё будет именно так. Модераторы достаточно загружены, а потому вероятность подобного контакта будет зависеть исключительно от вашего предшествующего вклада в сообщество, то есть вашей ценности как участника.
>
> Если вы проигнорируете модераторское предупреждение, ваша учётная запись будет временно заблокирована...

Меня заблокировали на 3 недели, сначала на 1 неделю (модератором ruSO), а потом ещё на 2 (менеджером сообщества) без всяких обсуждений и предупреждений. Хотя мне, если честно, хватило бы простого предупреждения и вопрос был бы исчерпан.

Мне интересно:

- В каких случаях сначала даётся предупреждение?
- Как высчитывается срок блокировки (в целом и первой)?
- Или предыдущие 2 вопроса ни от чего не зависят, кроме как хотелки модератора?

Comment: даже причину Вам не сказали?

Comment: @Dev18 технически невозможно назначить блокировку не уведомив участника о причинах.

Comment: @aepot а кто решает причину, в том плану, что факты всегда есть=обоснованные?, или бывает, ну по типу вопрос не понравился модер заминусовал и сам же удалил, ну типа качество же низкое минус же стоит‍♀️.......так вот и блокировкой кто такое решает?, что участник нарушил и как то это фиксируется, доказательствами всмысле?

Comment: @Dev18 автор же сам пишет, что ему КМы добавили. Как вы думаете, есть ли причины и обоснованы ли они? Или же сначала модератор устроил произвол, а потом сотрудники тоже устроили произвол? Так что-ли? А рассуждение об удалениях потому что "захотелось" это не в рамках данного вопроса, а отдельный вопрос. И ответ на него кроется примерно там же где и вопрос: а доверяете ли вы модераторам в принципе?

Comment: @Dev18 Всё было сказано в сообщении от модераторов. Спорить было бессмысленно т.к. всё было почти очевидно. Просто я ожидал небольшого конфиденциального разговора, после чего сам бы принял все нужные меры. А так 3 недели было очень скучно :)

Comment: @aepot Я думаю метка с произволом лишняя т.к. я работу модераторов не расцениваю как произвол в моём случае. Просто наказание было (как по мне) очень суровым, особенно для первого раза и всё. Вопрос чисто про критерии без всяких возмущений в сторону модераторов

Comment: @EzioMercer мы вас спрашивали, и следили за страничкой. Главное, если вы поняли причину, согласны с решением, вернулись и такое не повторится

Comment: @Dev18 Да, видел ваши вопросы, но не мог отвечать, к сожалению. Спасибо за интерес к моему профилю :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блокировка (бан) - это не что-то непоправимое, сам там бывал (хотя и не могу сказать, что заслуженно), это временное состояние. В некоторых случаях, когда модератор(ы) обращает своё внимание на участника из-за его "поведения" на сайте, например, нарушение [Норм поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), действительно можно обойтись предупреждением. Тем более, что участник просто мог сразу не понять где и как он нарушает эти нормы. И если участник принял это к сведению и не становится рецидивистом, то бан действительно не обязателен.

Но есть и другие случаи, к которым, в частности, относятся нарушения при голосованиях, например, создание фиктивный аккаунтов для накручивания репутации, или договорное голосование между двумя и более участниками. Если было обнаружено подобное, то блокировки не избежать. Если бы участник заранее явился с повинной о недостойном поведении с накруткой, то это ещё можно было бы свести только к удалению кукольных аккаунтов, пересчёту репутации и, вполне вероятно, отсутствии необходимости блокировки для основного аккаунта. В таких случаях нельзя обойтись "хватило бы простого предупреждения и вопрос был бы исчерпан" по вполне очевидным причинам - нарушение было осознанным и не было явки с повинной.

Продление блокировки в случае накрутки репутации может быть обусловлено обнаружением аналогичных случаев на других сайтах сети. Этим занимаются уже менеджеры сообществ и в причине блокировки тогда присутствует фраза "network-wide", т.е. блокируется учётка не на одном сайте, а по всей сети Stack Exchange. Можно считать это судом высшей инстанции на SE.

По длительности блокировок [есть рекомендации](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337009/339911) для модераторов. Хотя это всего лишь рекомендации и от них можно отойти, обычно они выполняются.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146502/discussion-on-answer-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.