# Ссылки на англоязычные публикации во внутренних страницах Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: дефект, локализация

Последую [совету @Nofate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4170/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B#comment13931_4170) и заведу список ссылок на англоязычные публикации, которые идут со внутренних страниц "Stack Overflow на русском".

Такие публикации следует перевести на русский язык и давать ссылку уже на переведённый текст.

Первые две будут ссылками на уже существующие вопросы. При обнаружении новых ссылок предлагаю добавлять их в текущий вопрос путём его редактирования, чтобы собрать в одном месте.

- [Ссылка на статью про избранные вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4170/176217)
- [The Future of Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) на странице [привилегии "Общее сообщения"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)
- На странице [привилегии "Отмечать тревогой"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

  - [Ответ не является ответом](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/81389/flagging-as-not-an-answer#81392)
  - [Никакая улучшающая справка не спасет сообщение](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous#93606)
  - [Не является вопросом](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question)
  - [Слишком специфичный](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized)
  - [Реклама](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work)
- [Как устроены комментарии](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) на странице привилегии ["Комментировать повсеместно"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)
- на странице привилегии ["Голосовать против"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

  - [голосование против вопросов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)
  - [дополнительные голоса для вопросов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/)
- Ссылка на [демократические выборы модераторов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/02/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) (возможно стоит заменить на [эту нашу статью](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1984/15479)) на [странице со списком модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).
- Ссылка [делитесь знаниями в стиле вопросов и ответов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) при [попытке задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Вероятно, нужно поменять на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
- На странице [Как публиковать ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

  - [призываем](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).
  - [отметить ваш ответ верным](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)
  - [свободную базу прикладных решений](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/22/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)
- На странице привилегии [Доступ к аналитике сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) ссылка [поддерживаются сообществом](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/).
- На странице [Репутация и модерация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) ссылка [бонусы за подключения к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/).
- [с указанием ссылки на источник](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) в подвале сайта.
- [Что такое бета?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta)

  - [назначает модераторов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) вообще кривая ссылка, в оригинале там https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/
  - [демократические выборы модератора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)
  - [семь ключевых вопросов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/10/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)
  - [достижения критической массы](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) кривая ссылка, в оригинале https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/
- [Справка по Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

  - [большинство опасных тегов отключено](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/260198)
  - [будет определяться метками вопроса](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)
  - [один из поддерживаемых кодов языка для оформления](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)
- На странице [Моя учётная запись](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) ссылка [Воспользуйтесь следующими инструкциями](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704).
- На странице [Ивентов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) ссылка на [«Не робот»](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win).
- На странице [Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators):

  - ["временных модераторов"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).
  - ["защиту на вопросы"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/).
  - ["временно приостанавливать доступ"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Comment: У теории модерации был перевод же?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не видел. Гугл в кэше содержит?

Comment: @alexolut ссылку на Голосовать "за" Николас заменил, я из вопроса её удалил вашего. Или лучше было пометить как "заменено"?

Comment: @Suvitruf а фиг его знает, как с такими вопросами вообще быть. Можно сделать ответ сюда же, общий, в который переносить сделанное из вопроса, а в вопросе удалять. А может и какой-то другой подход нужен, трудно сказать.

Comment: @Suvitruf как мне кажется, лучше делать как в ревизии номер 8. Удалять и писать комментарий к правке. Зачеркнутый текст только захламляет пост.

Comment: @alexolut хорошо. Когда Николас добавит ссылки, которые я его попросил сегодня, поправлю пост.