# Постановка метки на строку с гиперссылкой в случае, если она ведёт на не переведённую на русский язык статью

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, справка

Прочитал статью о [коллективном переводе сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC). Хоть я и не переводчик, меня заинтересовал один вопрос.

Если переводится строка, в которой есть гиперссылка на англоязычную статью одного из сайтов сообщества [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) (и не только этих сайтов), необходимо ли указывать после ссылки в скобках *«(англ.)»*. Ведь если надпись на гиперссылке переведена на русский, она должена содержать метку, что статья англоязычная или её (надпись) и вовсе не стоит переводить.

Собственно, как пример, возьму ситуацию, когда пользователь создаёт вопрос на сайте, то он видит в конце страницы с вопросом переключатель с надписью:

> **Ответить на собственный вопрос** – [делитесь знаниями в стиле вопросов и
> ответов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).
>
> [image: снимок экрана]

Пользователь, не зная английского языка, переходит по ссылке и видит перед собой неродной язык. Не самый приятный сюрприз. По-хорошему, эту статью надо перевести и изменить ссылку.

Но сейчас другой вопрос. Скажем, я пишу описание метки. На англоязычной Википедии достаточно хорошее описание (или описание метки я беру с SO, где есть ссылка на англоязычную википедию). Русская версия может либо совсем отсутствовать, либо значительно отличаться от английской. В таком случае я указываю на англоязычную статью. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/wav/info).

В скобочках я указал, что ссылка ведёт на англоязычную статью

> Больше информации о формате на
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)  (англ.)

Пользователь будет заранее знать, что статья на английском.

Так же можно и с переводом поступать:

> **Ответить на собственный вопрос** – [делитесь знаниями в стиле вопросов и
> ответов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) (англ.)

Собственно, вопрос. Нужно ли это указывать? Если да, какие есть исключения?

Comment: Есть уже некоторый [список](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4178/176217) (не полный) подобных ссылок. По-хорошему, все тексты надо перевести и указать новую ссылку.

Comment: Перевод - это идеал. А пока его нет (а при ссылке на др. сайты скорее всего и не будет), стоит ли ставить такого рода метки? Можно пока лишь собрать статистику пользователей с помощью голосования. Может только мне мои тараканы в голове мешают. Вряд ли кто будет голосовать, но вдруг.

Comment: @alexolut Если и делать перевод, то где его размещать? У RuSO ведь нет блога. Не на мету же? А так, у переводчиков есть возможность менять ссылки на статьи в переводе или это могут только те, кто корректирует движок RuSO?

Comment: @EgorTrutnev, переводы справки вполне и на мете выкладывались

Comment: @Grundy Ну, скажем, сообщение-справку о блокировке аккаунта размещать на мете уж точно не стоит. У блога другая структура

Comment: Перевод вполне можно размещать на Мете. Но для начала стоит убедиться, что его действительно ещё нет.

Answer (score 6):

Идею с указанием языка ссылки поддерживаю. Периодически забываю, что английский знают не все, поэтому надо взять на заметку. Правда я часто сохраняю исходный английский заголовок, поэтому язык очевиден.

Предлагаю следующий алгоритм:

1. Если можете перевести полностью, то следует перевести с указанием источника.
2. Если можете перевести частично, то следует перевести важную часть и сослаться на источник с указанием языка.
3. Если не можете перевести, то следует привести ссылку на источник с указанием языка.

Было бы замечательно, если бы ссылки между сайтами Stack Exchange автоматически отмечались иконками. В том числе традиционной википедийной иконкой в случае ссылок на внешние сайты.

Можно даже монетизировать иконки сайтов, как на большом СО монетизируются иконки на метках.