# Ссылки на blog.stackoverflow.com из справочного центра

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

К примеру в [справке по защищённым вопросам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) есть ссылка на [запись в EN блоге](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/).

Была какая-то особенная причина делать это именно так? Почему не сделали эту статья как часть справки, тогда бы можно было её перевести.

Там такие ссылки много где встречаются. Возможно ли сделать все эти блого-записи отдельными статьями в справке?

Comment: Думаю, просто исторически так сложилось. Мы стараемся переводить такие статьи на Мете, и на нее ссылаться из справки, в свою очередь.

Comment: У меня вот [такой список](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4178/176217) начат...

Comment: @alexolut а кто и где переводит их? И как помочь с этим? В transifex этого нет?

Comment: @Suvitruf страницы справки находятся в каких-то спец.файлах у Николая в подсобке :)

Comment: @Suvitruf У меня был свой список (доска Trello), где я отслеживал что я планирую перевести. Вероятно, надо бы это дело синхронизировать как–то, чтобы не делать работу дважды. Буду крайне благодарен за помощь! Для того, чтобы помочь: переведите любую из публикаций в блоге, опубликуйте ее на Мете и оповестите меня, чтобы я выставил нужные ссылки.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хорошо ^_^

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6344/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%89%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%85

Comment: @Suvitruf Большое спасибо! Обновил страницу справки!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky рад помочь)