# Статус защищённых вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка

По просьбе модераторов с Super User было решено установить новый статус защищённым вопросам. Защищённые вопросы теперь подобны [защищённым статьям на Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_policy) — **они больше не позволяют оставлять сообщения анонимными пользователями**.

Защищённые вопросы указываются в стандартном формате внизу сообщения:

> Защищён участником {имя модератора} {время}.
>
> Вопрос защищён от ответов в духе «Спасибо!», «У меня тоже!» или спама,
>   публикуемого новичками. Чтобы опубликовать ответ, вам необходимо
>   заработать не менее 10 баллов репутации на сайте (бонус за ассоциацию
>   учётных записей не учитывается).

Такой механизм необходим, так как некоторые из наиболее популярных вопросов на Super User привлекали много шума от случайных пользователей, не понимающих принципов работы системы, - пользователи, оставляющие благодарственные сообщения вроде "Спасибо, это помогло мне!" или "Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой, может ли кто-нибудь помочь?". И многие других подобных сообщений.

Просто посмотрите [один из примеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714076/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-office-365):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие удалённые сообщения видны только в том случае, если у вас есть доступ к [инструментам модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (необходимо 10.000 репутации).

**Если вы видите вопрос, который привлекает много бесполезные ответов, пожалуйста, отметьте его тревогой для привлечения внимания модератора. Они отметят вопрос как защищённый.** В настоящий момент минимальная репутация, начиная с которой вы можете публиковать ответ в такие вопросы, довольно низка - вам нужно всего 10 репутации.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации [«New Protected Question Status»](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Если вы видите вопрос, который привлекает много бесполезные ответов, пожалуйста, отметьте его тревогой для привлечения внимания модератора. Они отметят вопрос как защищённый.

Что-то подозреваю, что это не требуется:

1. Привилегия [Защищённые вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) даётся при достижении 15k репутации. При ней пользователь может сам защитить вопрос и снять защиту.

   [image]
2. Дух сам защищает вопросы с большим количеством удалённых ответов.

   [image]

PS: Сейчас есть всего 33 пользователя с репутацией больше 10k, но меньше 15k.