# Заменить ссылку на пост про защищённые вопросы в статье "Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, защищённые-вопросы

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас там ссылка на https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status.

У нас есть перевод этой записи: [Статус защищённых вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6344/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%89%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2). Нужно бы заменить ссылочку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Внес необходимые изменения.

Comment: Снова надо убрать id юзера из ссылки.

Comment: @älёxölüt   (¬‿¬ )