# Стоит ли для всех ссылок на англоязычные посты сделать заглушки?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка

В контексте этого треда: [Ссылки на англоязычные публикации во внутренних страницах Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4178/15479)

У нас в справке очень много ссылок на англоязычные посты. Сегодня наткнулся у нас на такую вот заглушку для одной из статьи: [Что-такое мета-метки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/15479)

Имеет ли смысл для всех подобных ссылок сделать заглушки и по мере возможностей переводить?

Comment: Заглушки в виде ссылок на что? Создать N вопросов на Мете и наполнять их? Имхо, никто этим заниматься не будет. Достаточно каталога ссылок, требующих перевода.

Comment: @älёxölüt я раз в 3 года могу переводить :D

Comment: Бабушку через дорогу.